# Duplicate nested form or fields based on a number with gravity forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

Based on a number field I want to duplicate a number of subforms in a form. I believe nested form is one way of achieving this.

I would like the advanced field (that is to be duplicated) to have the following structure:
Number input field for each items. There can be about 40 items listed.

The only possible advanced field to get that is list field. But I would like to invert the columns (listing the items) into rows. Then group the rows into columns so that we have 10x4 grid, where each cell in the grid has the item label and input field.

This is the output wanted with list field or some capable field when a number of rooms is specified:

[image]

This adds fields based on a number:
http://demos.gravitywiz.com/set-number-of-list-field-rows-by-field-value/
But instead of adding rows I want to add a set of duplicate fields so that it looks like the above form sketch up.

How can this be done using gravity forms? I guess it is all about editing the HTML and JS for one of the field types? There is no ready made field for this. How can I edit the list field to do this? The +/- buttons can be removed.

Comment: The best would be go for nested forms where the sub form contains the bedroom items labels and quantity field. But how can I achieve nested forms? Is there a hint/snippet somewhere to do this?

Comment: Each nested form can then be duplicated based on the number of rooms entered. But not sure what code and where to edit. What hook/filter can I use in the functions.php?